# Probability question about states and incomes

Tags: probability

**Question:**

Twelve percent of all US households are in California. A total of 3.3 percent of all US households earn over 250000 per year, while a total of 6.3 percent California households earn over 250000 per year. If a randomly chosen US household earns over 250,000 per year, what is the probability that it is from California?

**My attempt:**

$$\Pr(\text{earn}>250000)=0.033$$

$$\Pr(\text{California})=0.12$$

$$P(\text{earn}>250000/\text{California})=0.063$$

$$\Pr(\text{earn}>250000\text{ and California})=0.12\times0.063=7.56\times10^{-3}$$

Then

$$\Pr(\text{earn}>250000\text{ and not in California})=0.033-(7.56\times10^{-3})=0.02544$$

Then 
$$\Pr(\text{California} \mid \text{earn}>250000)=\frac{7.56\times10^{-3}}{0.033}=0.2291$$

But the answer given in the instructors manual is 0.2066.
What is wrong with my logic?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I edited your question to use LaTeX so that it is more readable and understandable, and hopefully attracts some answers.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your logic if the question is stated exactly as you've typed. You get .2066 only if the 3.3% is on the other 88% of the population.

Comment: Thanks @DavidM,@Matthew Liu